# BC30456: 'bindData' is not a member of 'shoppingCart1.ShoppingCart'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Class File

```
Public Function bindData() As String
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        'Dim objDA As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim myRow As SqlDataReader
        Dim comd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", con)
        con.Open()
        myRow = comd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim strRowGen As String = ""
        While myRow.Read()
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TR>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(0) & "</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(1) & "</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD>" & myRow.GetValue(2) & "</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "<TD><a href='#' onclick=""javascript:document.Form1.action='ShoppingPage.aspx?Actn=Add&itemId=" & myRow.GetValue(0) & "';document.Form1.submit();"">Add To Cart</TD>"
            strRowGen = strRowGen & "</TR>"
            'cellshoping.InnerHtml = strRowGen
        End While
        Return strRowGen
    End Function
```

ASPX CODE BEHIND

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Put user code to initialize the page here
    'Load data by calling function bindData()
            Dim sCart = New ShoppingCart
            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

                cellshoping.InnerHtml = sCart.bindData()
            End If
End Sub
```

Now when i run the page i get this error " BC30456: 'bindData' is not a member of 'shoppingCart1.ShoppingCart'.
"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your aspx page and your shopping cart class are not in the same namespace.

You either need to add

```
Namespace shoppingCart1
```

(and end namespace) to your shoppingcart class or remove the namespace from the page.

Comment: Try this: at the top of your page code behind, add `Option Explicit On` on one line and `Option Strict On` on another line. This could highlight some problematic areas in the code. I suspect that there is another class called shoppingcart somewhere that is getting picked up instead of the one that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the heirarchy of the class. In your cs file if its a pure class file, not a code behind. You must have

```
using System;

namespace yourNameSpace
{
  public class yourClassName
  {
     public function binddata()
     {
            // your logic
     }
   }
}


aspx.cs/vb

partial class aspxClass
{
   dim yourObjectName as new yourClassName()
   //do whatever with the object


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error occured frequently while deploying a project in visual studio 2005 or 2008.
The main reason of this error is the existance of duplicate dll names in the bin folder for the same project, alll what you have to do is to remove the unused dll file from the bin folder